# Jmeter Importing using .xlsx file extension

Tags: rest, import, jmeter, xlsx

Hello can someone help me import .xlsx on Jmeter, I tried to use  this configuration unfortunately it doesn't work. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Screenshot:

File Location

[image]

1st Payload/Request
[image]

2nd Payload Request:

[image]

Header

[image]

Response:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using "Files upload" tab and your server expects [multipart/form-data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) content type you should tick the corresponding box in JMeter's HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

Going forward be informed that it's possible to record the file upload request from your browser (or other application) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), **just make sure to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to JMeter's "bin" folder** so JMeter could properly generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: Actually I tried to tick multipart/form-data unfortunately it didn't work on my end.  the response I'm getting is this one

"java.io.IOException: RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for multipart"